# Datatable and XTS multiple subset speed

Tags: r, data.table, xts

Am i using `data.table` incorrectly? I am looping through and subsetting but comparing it to `xts`, its much slower. For 2026 rows and 9 columns, i get like 30secs for `data.table` while for 'xts' i get like around 2 seconds.

Below are two sample functions I am using, `lb` can be a vector of numbers like `c(10,20,30,40,50,60)` and `data` is a xts or any other object. To replicate my performance, have `data` be a `xts object`

```
DT <- function(lb,data){
    require(data.table)
    #lb = c(20,40,60,120,250)
    data.core <- data.table(coredata(data))
    for(i in (max(lb)+1):nrow(data.core)){
        lb.sbst = list()

        for(j in 1:length(lb)){
            lb.sbst[[j]] = data.core[(i-lb[j]):(i-1),]
        }

    }
}

XTS <- function(lb,data){
    #lb = c(20,40,60,120,250)
    for(i in (max(lb)+1):nrow(data)){
        lb.sbst = list()

        for(j in 1:length(lb)){
            lb.sbst[[j]] = data[(i-lb[j]):(i-1),]
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What you're doing is not the most efficient way to use either data.table or xts objects. If you provide more detail on what you're _actually_ trying to accomplish, someone might be able to help you.

Comment: I am trying test out loop structure. It is to be used to calculate various things like rolling statistics, etc. I understand there are cleaner functions like `rollapplyr` but I don't see much noticeable speedups. Is there faster way of doing rolling statistical computation? Are there functions that can utilize the power of multi-core/threads for rolling statistics? Note that for a lot of my rolling statistics, it requires multiple lookbacks.